# For temporary registers in the asm statement, should I use clobber or dummy output?

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

As mentioned in the title of this question, when I modify some registers inside the asm statement, for a temporary reason, which option is better in between the clobber and dummy output?

For example, I implemented two versions of the exchange function in the [link](https://godbolt.org/z/fzbkpC), and found that two versions generate the same amount of output instructions.

Which version should I use? Should I use the one with the dummy output to allow the compiler choose the register that may optimize entire function as much as possible?

If the answer is yes, then when should I use the clobber list? Is it only okay to use the clobber list when one instruction requires you to load its operand to the specific registers? such as syscall instruction requires its parameter should be located in register rdi   rsi   rdx   r10   r8    r9??

Comment: Indeed [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers) explicitly mentions this: "Rather than allocating fixed registers via clobbers to provide scratch registers for an asm statement, an alternative is to define a variable and make it an early-clobber output as with a2 and a3 in the example below."

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for referencing the manual. Out of curiosity, when we consider a calling convention of amd64, some registers can be freely used inside the functions; and we could implement some functions by only using those registers inside the asm statement. Why allowing the compiler to choose the registers to be used is better than the mentioned one? Is it for the case that the asm statement is used with some C code?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: because functions can inline, maybe into a loop that calls other functions, thus the compiler would want to give it inputs in call-preserved registers.  If you were writing a stand-alone function that the compiler always has to `call`, all you get from inline asm instead of stand-alone is the compiler handling calling-convention differences and C++ name-mangling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normally let the compiler pick registers for you, using an early-clobber dummy output with any required constraints<sup>1</sup>.  This gives it flexibility to do register allocation for the function.

<sup>1</sup>  e.g. you can use `+&Q` to get one of RAX/RBX/RCX/RDX: registers that have an AH/BH/CH/DH.  If you wanted to unpack 8-bit fields with `movzbl %h[input], %[high_byte]`
; `movzbl %b[input], %[low_byte]` ; `shr $16, %[input]`, you'd need a register that has it's 2nd 8-bit chunk aliased to a high-8 register.

> Out of curiosity, when we consider a calling convention of amd64, some registers can be freely used inside the functions; and we could implement some functions by only using those registers inside the asm statement. Why allowing the compiler to choose the registers to be used is better than the mentioned one?

**Because functions can inline, maybe into a loop that calls other functions, thus the compiler would want to give it inputs in call-preserved registers.** If you were writing a stand-alone function that the compiler always has to call, all you get from inline asm instead of stand-alone is the compiler handling calling-convention differences and C++ name-mangling.

Or maybe the surrounding code uses some instructions that require fixed registers, like `cl` for shift counts or RDX:RAX for `div`.

---

> when should I use the clobber list?  ...
> such as syscall instruction requires its parameter should be located in register rdi rsi rdx r10 r8 r9??

Normally you'd use input constraints instead, so only the `syscall` instruction itself is inside the inline asm.  But `syscall` (the instruction itself) clobbers RCX and R11, so system calls made using it unavoidably destroy user-space's RCX and R11.  There's no point using dummy outputs for these, unless you have a use for the return address (RCX) or RFLAGS (R11).  So yes, clobbers are useful here.

```
// the compiler will emit all the necessary MOV instructions
#include <stddef.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

// the compiler will emit all the necessary MOV instructions
//static inline 
size_t sys_write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t len) {
    size_t retval;
    asm volatile("syscall"
        : "=a"(retval)  //   EDI     RSI       RDX
        : "a"(__NR_write), "D"(fd), "S"(buf), "d"(len)
         , "m"(*(char (*)[len]) buf)   // dummy memory input: the asm statement reads this memory
        : "rcx", "r11"    // clobbered by syscall
           // , "memory"  // would be needed if we didn't use a dummy memory input
    );
    return retval;
}
```

A non-inline version of this compiles as follows (with [`gcc -O3` on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoILosAMwB0CDdg4AGAIJyFSlZnVamggLYB6ESzw70x0xesrNzdVAgQHNBcABzwGTGJVAHdYhlVMF0JVJgZUsIcWTAlBQSZiAE9VAFkAeQA1VQUdYhFkAjxUFkEA4J0mNuQGlgYFBwDBPAAvTAB9AlVBMsFpxOJCTAgFOf10UlU0TrnkBFLVACoAIxF9XfGp2dU4lgBKdQB2PitVL/nJmbniTAEABu2Q0H0s3yyrlUQNQzDacQg3C4C0EyGyDGRAUhkJA6i4XA0ABEmMiIADgdkXqpgt9sESAJI4gBKAGUmTjVMyiQANbGc1R45GkgkQabTAByzOWqwImCeu2RRLJ2wV%2BK4rLJl30auR6DJjye/IFioJLjJpwgRxOEFORoArDxHhx7USXtrqTSQugRC4XBUXOkSBUFFERAQ8XkoS55gQ%2BulMCx/pgmOhBKEEN5VIGXMHjTihQTxAAPZGmrjEWi0ZGQ2lKVDnc7xTDoVTnCqo9E5fMC2nlnN5glfWmJUQMVtN1QFFsthr6JIOfDoFhgKRzESCBxMVQ%2Bv0BoPlQZhgj5o2ycGQiliFiqCkgzHngIcV7KqxPt9WW5/He%2B87TVEymsGxJqo2y7PsOh7McCQXFcNy/PchpvBe3xfvcd6go%2BnzfM4MawvCsTrD23zIrmQL4vaLo8NsLpEqalFcPaLZ4C6mgsKxJ4EsRXykag5HcJRjrarR9ECcQ4ysex9qaJxhLYZyvH8YxVHOq6omMcQ6CltJUkyVi8k4sinYYvpEICoWhKyCSZIYQw1K0l89Ict8bLOZC3J8gZuLqiKXBipK0orGsuqOjRrrIsQKroCFPDCeFRZalcMWqcqCWioa3FfP2FpWtBqi2g6TqJrR7pJd8tK7v62YHiGLDHpG4TRrG8aBiBAKpumYRZgO5SZRZmksQS5biYNXDDVpZbqiWk0RVWNblSE9aNs2E4dosXaYl5nJ9uqPVlPNI5jhO%2BSYDOrZ4POiSLngy6ruum5ZD%2Be7Vbmh6huGp5gvmV7EDetlfW%2BL4BFICoMNI9pSKQLDSOYkOoNImj8Pw8yiOIoxcLItCQxGUiw08CoANYgAALAAHIY9qyPapOyK8ACctB06TXC0LT9qMNIxOQy4dDmOYUMw3D0iQ4IID8zjeOkHAsBIJEMRxGQFBWqg0SEcQIDAMzpD6LEcriZQ5yC6Q5wKKUZTSFjpCRK1BDVEM5u45DWAuKwwBxEb%2BAAq0eBApgouO6QmDFoU4aSFIlubJgYPh5DwznMQZuaBgYeWwQqw8zHoOuygSO8IweDnKLkAKqgURtB0/sALTVLIIuoxIdCg%2BDkPQwH8NSMWpMAGyV13xOqMAyADOTXD5bghAkPimO7EnqsK1PtAvIjvD8Njgv46Q4SpvElCEyA9q0IYxN97QXdcOYpPmLQrzd2N0dcwLbfC0IYukBLINN1IXAt0b7dr47G9fYjQ6CTIAA%3D%3D%3D)), because the function-calling convention nearly matches the system-call convention:

```
sys_write(int, char const*, unsigned long):
    movl    $1, %eax
    syscall
    ret
```

It would have been really silly to use clobbers on any of the input registers and put a `mov` inside the asm:

```
size_t dumb_sys_write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t len) {
    size_t retval;
    asm volatile(
        "mov %[fd], %%edi\n\t"
        "mov %[buf], %%rsi\n\t"
        "mov %[len], %%rdx\n\t"
        "syscall"
        : "=a"(retval)  //   EDI     RSI       RDX
        : "a"(__NR_write), [fd]"r"(fd), [buf]"r"(buf), [len]"r"(len)
         , "m"(*(char (*)[len]) buf)   // dummy memory input: the asm statement reads this memory
        : "rdi", "rsi", "rdx", "rcx", "r11"
           // , "memory"  // would be needed if we didn't use a dummy memory input
    );

    // if(retval > -4096ULL) errno = -retval;

    return retval;
}

dumb_sys_write(int, char const*, unsigned long):
    movl    %edi, %r9d
    movq    %rsi, %r8
    movq    %rdx, %r10
    movl    $1, %eax     # compiler generated before this
  # from inline asm
    mov %r9d, %edi
    mov %r8, %rsi
    mov %r10, %rdx
    syscall
  # end of inline asm
    ret
```

And besides that, you're not letting the compiler take advantage of the fact that `syscall` *doesn't* clobber any of its input registers.  The compiler might well still want `len` in a register, and using a pure input constraint lets it know that the value will still be there afterwards.

---

You might also use clobbers if you're using any instructions that implicitly use certain registers, but neither the input nor output of those instructions is a direct input or output of the asm statement.  That would be rare, though, unless you're writing a whole loop or large block of code in inline asm.

Or maybe if you're wrapping a `call` instruction.  (It's hard to do this safely, especially because of the red-zone, but people do try to do this).  You don't get to choose which registers the code clobbers, so you just tell the compiler about it.

Comment: Really appreciate for perfect clarification on usage of clobber list. I could understand most of the example, but the dummy memory input. Why we need either a dummy memory input or the memory clobber? Is it because some pre-accessed content from the memory region in the [buf ~ (buf+len)), which may be stored in some register, can be used in the later program part (because of the compiler optimization)? In other words, is it used to make the compiler flush the register and make the later part of the program access the new content written by the kernel as a result of syscall?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: `"r"(buf)` does *not* imply that the inline asm statement dereferences the pointer to read the pointed-to block of memory, or even the first element.  So if you have `buf[1] = 'a'` before the sys_write, and `buf[1] = 'b'` after, the optimizer could treat the first once as a dead store and just store `'b'` either before or after the `syscall` instruction depending on what it decides!  As far as the optimizer is concerned, storing to `buf[1]` is totally independent of the `asm` statement, unless you have a dummy input or a `"memory"` clobber.

Comment: And it might be a dumb question, why the compiler outputs the dumb instructions that move the parameter back and forth? It may be reasonable to think that compiler knows subsequent mov instructions do not change anything. Is it because GCC only considers the operands of extended asm, but not the instructions inside the asm template? I've read that GCC doesn't care about the semantics of the instructions inside the asm statement, but I am not sure whether this example explain that one.

Comment: @JaeHyukLee: That's actually a good question.  It's because your clobbers told it that RDI, RSI, and RDX can't be used for input operands.  The clobber list is like early-clobber outputs, they're assumed to be clobbered *before* inputs are read from those registers.  And yeah, GNU C inline asm is purely a text substitution according to the constraints and the `%modifier0` / `%modifier[name]` sequences inside the template.  The compiler has no idea you used `mov` instructions yourself.  That's your own fault; never do that.

Comment: Appreciate for kind answers. For the first answer, does it mean that wrong data could be written to the file because the compiler may optimize in a way that buf[1] = 'b' is executed before the sys_write even though it is located after the sys_write in the code? If it is correct, I am curious whether the memory barrier prevents the **compiler** from arranging the memory access operations around the asm statement or **processor** from speculatively reading or writing to the memory.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.  Or the `buf[1] = 'a'` could be moved after, and then dropped.  A `"memory"` clobber is purely a compile-time reordering barrier.  For a strongly-ordered ISA like x86, `asm("" ::: "memory");` is sufficient to block all reordering except StoreLoad, which can also happen at runtime.  Remember that within a single thread of execution, the CPU will always preserve the illusion of your instructions running in program order, regardless of what other cores see if they look at your memory.  https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time

Comment: @PeterCordes If you are using ```asm goto``` statements what is the best practice ([given that goto label forbids output registers])(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)?

Comment: @Noah: IDK, you might have to write more of your function in asm so the branch target is part of the same asm block.  Or the output could be in memory with `asm volatile` and a `"memory"` clobber, unless that would be terrible because you want the value hot in a register.  I guess another option could be to break up your asm into more blocks including GCC6 flag output operands so all the conditionals can be done with pure C.  Just throwing out ideas here; it's not something I've had to deal with.  I don't usually recommend actually using inline asm for performance.